# Не работает опция --sport

Tags: linux, iptables

К примеру, я получаю много UDP обращений:

[image: tcpdump incoming connections UDP]

Мне нужно блокировать все соединения, которые со стороны клиента инициируются НЕ с порта 27005.

Думаю этот код должен работать:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport :27004 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 27006: -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 27005 -j ACCEPT
```

Но он не работает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1. как вы определили «неработоспособность»? укажите это прямо в вопросе, пожалуйста. 2. вы добавляете правила *netfilter-а* в конец таблицы *filter*. что ещё в ней находится? `sudo iptables-save -t filter`.

Comment: если в таблице *filter* уже есть правила, разрешающие принятие пакетов, которые вы пытаетесь *reject-ить*, то имеет смысл не добавлять новые правила (`-A`) в конец таблицы, а вставлять их в начало (`-I`).

Comment: Файл выглядит так

`#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
iptables -I INPUT -s 31.204.100.0/22 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport :27004 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 27006: -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 27005 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 95.213.195.1 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Он не работает т.к. этот скриншот был сделан после команд
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport :27004 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 27006: -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 27005 -j ACCEPT
ТЦП не должен был показать эти строки насколько я понимаю но показал

Comment: файл выше (баш скрипт) запускается кроном на старте системы.

Comment: На картинке вывод `tcpdump` (если я не ошибаюсь). Проблема в том, что `tcpdump` получает пакеты до того, как их блокирует iptables, так что правильность настройки вы им не проверите.

Comment: Как проверить тогда? У меня на порт где софтверный сервер игры идет ддос с разных портов, очень много соединений, просто грузят ЦП

Comment: А ещё в iptables есть отрицание, так что три правила можно заменить одним: `iptables ... -p udp \! --sport 27005 -j REJECT` (тут я экранировал восклицательный знак от интерпретации шеллом).

Comment: Для проверки можно смотреть счётчики срабатывания в iptables, можно ещё настроить логгирование отдельных пакетов, но тут надо осторожно, чтобы не заполонить логи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Две вещи:

1. Используйте `-I` вместо `-A`, тогда вы гарантируете, что правило добавляется в начало цепочки, и ничего ему не препятствует.
2. Контроллируйте работоспособность цепочки с помощью правила `-j LOG` в конце,
   а не с помощью `tcpdump`.

`tcpdump` не может *в принципе* показать, что делает `iptables`,
потому что он работает на интерфейсе (между канальным и сетевым уровнем), и трафик начинает обрабатываться iptables/netfilter позже.

В остальном у вас всё правильно.